# ASPxGridview Edit Form Find Control

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm trying to Find a control in my edit form just before I hit the submit button on it(custom), however it isnt returning any value entered in the memo, even though I have inputted some value. It seems like its resetting. Its not binding to anything.

Code:

```
Dim Memo As ASPxMemo =   CType(ASPxGridView_BranchQueue.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ASPxMemo_ResubmissionRationale"), ASPxMemo)

    MsgBox(Memo.Text.ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Devexpress example for HTMLEDItor in AspxGridView, but its the same.
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E296

Where do you specify the memo in yor aspx file. 
FindEditFormTemplateControl method is used when the control you are looking for control is 
in `<EditForm>` tag of the AspxGridView.

For example:

```
 <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID">
        <Templates>
            <EditForm>
                <dx:ASPxMemo ID="ASPxMemo1" runat="server" Height="71px" Width="170px">
                            </dx:ASPxMemo>
            </EditForm>
        </Templates>
```